# Using modal view frame size in subview layout constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

**Problem**: I am having some issues using the correct frame values to simulate viewport percentages when sizing subviews of a modal view-controller. I would rather size subviews using layout constraints instead of explicit frame values.

The frame value is not correctly set for the modal view-controller up to and including `viewWillAppear`. The two methods that are called in sequence with the desired frame values are `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidAppear`. Thus far, these appear to be the only "hooks" I can use with access to the correct frame values.

These methods are not easily useable because:

- `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called multiple times with what I am assuming are intermediary frame values. Setting the same constraint(s) multiple times throws an Auto Layout constraint error.

  ```objectivec
  // Multiple frame values return from viewWillLayoutSubviews
  {{0, 0}, {393, 783}}
  {{0, 0}, {393, 283.66666666666663}}
  ```
- `viewDidAppear` works better in that it is only called once with the final, desired frame value. However, by this point the views are added to the view hierarchy and shown on the screen. Then when setting the layout constraints, the screen brief displays the unconstrained layout before displaying the constrained layout.

**Workaround solution**: Using `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and deactivating old constraints before activating new constraints to avoid constraint conflicts. This can be done by either iterating through `modal.view.constraints` or maintaining a state variable (strong reference) to the original constraints on the first call of `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. This does not seem to be that clean of a solution.

```objectivec
// Utility function to activate constraints
void setConstraints (UIView* view, NSLayoutAnchor *leading, NSLayoutAnchor *trailing, NSLayoutAnchor *top, NSLayoutAnchor *bottom,
                   CGFloat cLeading, CGFloat cTrailing, CGFloat cTop, CGFloat cBottom, NSArray<NSLayoutConstraint*>* __strong *constraints) {
  NSArray *newConstraints = @[
      [view.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:leading constant:cLeading],
      [view.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:trailing constant:cTrailing],
      [view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:top constant:cTop],
      [view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:bottom constant:cBottom]
  ];
  [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:*constraints];
  [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:newConstraints];
  *constraints = newConstraints;
}

// UIViewController "hook" with eventually correct frame value
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
  [self.recordingView setConstraints];
}

// Modal view-controller setting auto layout constraints based on layoutMarginsGuide and current modal frame values
- (void) setConstraints {
  UILayoutGuide *guide = self.layoutMarginsGuide;
  CGFloat width = self.frame.size.width;
  CGFloat height = self.frame.size.height;
  setConstraints(self.textField, guide.leadingAnchor, guide.trailingAnchor, guide.topAnchor, guide.topAnchor,
                 0.05*width, -0.05*width, 0.0, 0.2*height, &textFieldConstraints);
  setConstraints(self.progressBar, guide.leadingAnchor, guide.trailingAnchor, self.textField.bottomAnchor, self.textField.bottomAnchor,
                 0.05*width, -0.05*width, 0.08*height, 0.1*height, &progressBarConstraints);
}
```

**Question**: Is there a better way to do this that I am not seeing? Or am I not really supposed to be using frame values as viewport width/height percentages (similar to CSS)?

Comment: Very confusing... is `textField` actually a `UITextView`? And you want it to be 20% of the height of the controller's view? And `progressBar` is a `UIProgressView`? And that should be 10% of the height? And both should be 90% of the width, centered horizontally?

Comment: Is the end goal to simply position the text field and progress bar within the recording view or should the size of the recording view be adjusted based on the layout of the text field and the progress bar?

Comment: It also is very confusing that you want the leading edge of the text field and progress view to be 5% of the view's width further in from the view's leading margin. Is that really your intent? Or do you really just want the leading edge of the text field and progress bar to be 5% of the view's width from the view's leading edge?

Comment: @DonMag Sorry about that. Yes `textField` is indeed a `UITextView`. And basically I want to position subviews based on viewport width/height percentages as you've described. The specific percentages are not particularly relevant.

Comment: @HangarRash The details of the layout are not really relevant. My question pertains more to how I would go about implementing viewport width/height percentages in UIKit for a modal view. If this is the incorrect way to go about positioning subviews, what is the preferred method/strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is asking about a general approach, the following is just an example for setting up the constraints for the text view within its superview.

```
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    // Set the width as a percentage of the superview's width
    [self.textView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.layoutMarginsGuide.widthAnchor multiplier:0.9],
    // Align in the center horizontally
    [self.textView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.layoutMarginsGuide.centerXAnchor],
    // Set the top
    [self.textView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor],
    // Rely on the intrinsic height of the text view or you can optionally set a specific height constraint if desired
]];
```

The first constraint is the one most relevant to your question. This shows how to make the text view be 90% the width of the superview's margin layout width. Adjust as needed. Maybe replace `self.layoutMarginsGuide.widthAnchor` with `self.widthAnchor` depending on your needs.

Set these up once and you're done. No need to update. As the width of the superview changes, so will the width of the text view.

---

If you want to set a `topAnchor`, `bottomAnchor`, `leadingAnchor`, or `trailingAnchor` to be a percentage of a view's height or width, then you need to use the longer form of creating the constraint.

The following would set the text view's `topAnchor` to be 30% of the superview's `bottomAnchor`:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.textView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:0.3 constant:0];
```

Then you need to activate it as usual.

Comment: This works well for the sizing of the subview. Thanks!
As a follow-up, what if I want to position the subview let's say 30% of the superview height from the topAnchor as opposed to just on the topAnchor? There doesn't seem to be an adaptive layout method to do that using a similar "multiplier" argument, only "constant" which is a fixed value.

Comment: @ennell I updated my answer with an example for that case.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it unfortunately causes an error `Invalid pairing of layout attributes.` This is because it is trying to constrain a `topAnchor` to a `heightAnchor`.
Source: https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit/issues/534

Comment: Try replacing `NSLayoutAttributeHeight` with `NSLayoutAttributeBottom`.

Comment: @ennell I've updated the answer to reflect that change. Glad it worked for you.